# Windows 10 cannot detect EVGA GTX 970 after 2 months of use

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I got my EVGA GTX 770 replaced by EVGA due warranty, so they sent me their GTX970. It worked fine for around 2 months until Windows stopped recognizing it.
I tried reinstalling drivers, reinstalling Windows 10, tried every single solution and the card was still undetected.
At this point I don't know if it is defective or not and I don't want to lose right away.

Solutions?

Comment: How exactly *Windows stopped recognizing it*?

Comment: @MichaelBay The Nvidia driver cannot detect the card

Comment: You should have said so, explicitly, i.e., described what happened *and* posted the **exact error message**. It may  not be a case "detection" but something else: If you have video not provided by other card/onboard chipset then the Nvidia IS working. Does you motherboard has some "multi-monitor" option and/or the possibility to enable/disable discrete graphics that you may inadvertently changed? Perhaps better to [edit] the question, describe the issue properly and add other hardware specs (motherboard).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a professional and my response is done with my little knowledge.
But, when you say that windows can not recognize your Graphic card.
Did you look at the devices manager ( by typing devmgmt.msc in th windows search bar)?
If it is the case, is the card in the list, and if yes whith what icon on it?
The other solution i often use to check the material is to create a live USB with any live linux distro, boot on it and look at the linux device manager to see if it detects the card. If not, it is PROBABLY a material problem (on the card itself or on the PCIe).
It could also be done with an other windows version on live USB if it exist, the idea is to check if the problem is soft or hard by checking the hard with an other soft...